# How do I identify Model from ActionFilter and bind json data to that Model

Tags: asp.net-core, action-filter, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm building CryptoActionFilter to decrypt api request and bind decrypted request to api models. I have different models for each api's, So I have to mention every actionname and their models to bind decrypted data to that model. Is there any other way where I don't have add actionname and model every time I add new api in my controller?

Here is my CryptoActionFilter code:

```
key = Convert.ToString(((RequestData)(context.ActionArguments["data"])).KEY);
data = Convert.ToString(((RequestData)(context.ActionArguments["data"])).DATAOBJ);

if (key != "" && data != "")
{
    aesKey = RSA.RSADecrypt(key);
    string jsonData = AES.Decrypt(aesKey, data);

    if (actionName == "SignIn" || actionName == "NativeSignIn")
    {
        LoginRequest data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginRequest>(jsonData);
        context.ActionArguments["data"] = data;
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
    else if (actionName == "GetMenu")
    {
        MenuRequest data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MenuRequest>(jsonData);
        context.ActionArguments["data"] = data;
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

I have 100+ api's like this, I'll have to mention everyone of them in my actionfilter, is there any sorted logic for this so that i don't need to touch my cryptoactionfilter everytime I create new api?

Comment: What's the type of your action parameters `data`?

Comment: Just slowly for me, so I understand your code: You are encrypting your payload (symmetrically), then passing the payload **AND the key** to your API? Is that correct? if so: What's the point? You can send it just unencrypted, if you already send the symmetric key in the payload since it adds exactly **zero security** over sending the payload unencrypted. Anyways, whats the point of encrypting it, just use SSL, that protects your payload already from MitM (assuming you don't get your ssl private keys stolen, which well... is the same as someone stealing your encryption key :P)

Comment: As for your solution: You know the controller and the action, you could use reflection to figure out the proper controller and action, with that you can read out its parameters. The first complex parameter is always serialized (by convention) from payload. Rest should be easy. However, non of this fixes the broken design of that API...

Comment: @itminus It can be any type, I want to find that type and bind the decrypted data using that type

Comment: @Tseng I'm encrypting my data with random AES key and then encrypting AES key with RSA public key from .pem file and then sending encrypted Key and Data to api side, after that in Crypto Filter I'm decrypting my Key with RSA private key from .pem file and decrypting data with that decypted key and binding it to specific model to hit the api. So my security is based on .pem secret key file, which will be on my server and no one can access it. now my question is I want to bind decryped json data to specific models for that api, I don't want to mention every api and model in my action filter

Comment: Why are you then deserializing it? Just decrypt the data and put it in `context.ActionArguments["data"]`, and call `base.OnActionExecuting(context)` and let ASP.NET Core's model binder do the rest?? Or is the data already data bound on this point? if you, you're approach seems bad and you should do the decryption much earlier (maybe as custom model binder) or as a middleware (which reads the input data, and write it into a different stream which is passed to the middlewares after it (similar to how compression is done)

Comment: @Tseng Because decrypted data is in string format, I have to convert it to Json format to bind it to the model

Comment: @ShreyasPednekar The problem is not about the action name but the actual `data` type (MenuRequest/LoginRequest/...) that you want to cast to. You need make the Filter/ModelBinder to realize the real target type. I think it's better to use a IModelBinder instead of a Filter and change your action method to  `SignIn(LoginRequest data)`,`GetMenu(MenuRequest data)`. In this way you'll get the real type dynamically without any hard code.

Comment: Yea the point is to do the decryption **before** the data binding happens. Maybe sending the key in a header, then you could do all the stuff and decrypt the payload as its streamed in a middleware. Then the middlewares after the decryption would get the decrypted payload in the request stream and you don't have to bother at all and its much more performant